# How to import module in jython?

Tags: python, jython

I am trying to import the Textblob module in Jython, but I am getting **NO MODULE WITH NAME** exception.
I have tried different modules but the same exception appears.
Though this question may seem vague thats the only problem.

Comment: did you install the TextBlob?

Comment: It's running in a python environment but when I try to run it as java program in Jython its giving me the exception? Should I upload the code snippet?

Comment: "I have tried different modules but the same exception appears". What modules? How can the problem be reproduced?

Answer (score 1):

```
Properties p = new Properties();
        p.setProperty("python.console.encoding", "UTF-8");
        PySystemState systemState = Py.getSystemState();
        systemState.path.append(new PyString("C:\\jython2.7.1\\Lib")); 
        systemState.path.append(new PyString("C:\\jython2.7.1\\Lib\\site-packages"));
        systemState.path.append(new PyString("C:\\jython2.7.1\\pkgs"));

        PythonInterpreter.initialize(System.getProperties(), p, new String[] {});
        PythonInterpreter python = new PythonInterpreter();


        python.exec("from nltk.corpus import stopwords\ncachedStopWords = stopwords.words('english')");
```

This is how I solved it,Hope it helps someone:)